# Exercise on Binomial probability

Tags: probability, permutations, combinations

Twelve identical  balls are distributed among three boxes. The probability that the first box contains three balls is?

my thoughts:as any ball has 3 ways to go to each box,there will be 3^12 ways for 12 balls to fill in 3 boxes

Thus there are 3^12 ways in which 12 balls can be placed in 3 boxes.

now ,number of ways in which three balls to be kept in first box is 12C3 and remaining 9 balls can be kept in other two boxes in 2^9 ways ,

so the probability is 12C3*2^9/3^12.
but why the number of ways in which three balls to be kept in first box is 12C3?
since balls are identical it should be only 1.please help me to sort this confusion.

my confusion:number of ways in whether the number of ways in which  three balls to be kept in first box is 12C3 or 1.

Comment: If each ball has equal chances to land in box1, box2 or box3 then you are dealing with [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution): 12 independent events with a probability of 1/3 on success (i.e. the ball lands in box1). To be found is P(X=3) where X stands for the number of balls landing in box1. BTW, this has no link with Bayes theorem so your title is misleading.

Comment: It cannot harm to think of the balls as distinct. Then there are 12C3 selections of 3 balls out of 12. These are the balls that land in box1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability for each ball to hit the first hole is $\frac{1}{3}$ thus the probability that exactly 3 among the 12 balls hit the first hole is:

$$\binom{12}{3}\times \left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^3\times \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^9$$