# Imagine $12$ identical balls that are placed in $3$ Different boxes. What is the probability that one of the boxes contains exactly $3$ balls?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Imagine $12$ identical balls that are placed in $3$ Different boxes. What is the probability that one of the boxes contains exactly $3$ balls?

**Provided Solution:** We have mentioned that boxes are different and one
particular box has 3 balls.

Then Number of ways are $\frac{{12 \choose 3}\cdot 2^9}{3^{12}}$

**My doubt** Why in solution it is ${12 \choose 3}$ even if it given that balls are identical  according to me it must be  $1$ because number of ways to select $3$ balls from $12$ identical balls is $1$

Am i missing anything?

**Reference Question [Exercise on Binomial probability](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3839643/exercise-on-binomial-probability)***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When we work over probability it does not matter whether the balls are distinct or identical. Beucause , when we select one ball to place any box , the selected ball become distict , because it is the first ball selected. Did you get the idea ? It is not anymore identical , because it is in our hands to place and it is the first one.It is valid for the rest , for example the second selected ball , it was the same as the others ,but when we take it from among the others , it become suddenly distinguishable , it become distinguishable because , it is "the second selected ball",now we are able to  distinguish it !. Now , you have all distinct balls when you place them , because all of have selection order to be distinguished.

When we comes to your question , we have $12$ balls each have different selected order ,i.e they can be distinguished from other by their selection order. Select $3$ of them to satify given condition. These balls can be second selected ball , sixth selected and tenth selected or third selected , fifth selected and seventh selected. So , you just need to select $3$ order among $12$ order by $C(12,3)$

Comment: With regard to your note, we are asked for the probability that a *particular* box receives exactly three balls, so it is not necessary to select the box which will receive three balls.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig yes , misreading  , i assumed that only one box contain exactly three balls , i wlledit it

Answer (score 0):

The $12\choose3$ refers to the event "a ball lands in the first box". There are 12 chances for that to happen, and it needs to happen on 3 occasions. The chances are distinct events, even if the balls are identical.