# Distributing $r$ balls into $n$ cells. What is the probability that exactly $m$ cells contain exactly $k$ balls?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-distributions, balls-in-bins

$r$ balls are randomly distributed into $n$ cells (the balls are indistinguishable).

What is the probability that there is **exactly** $m$ cells that contains **exactly** $k$ balls (each one)? That is, the rest of the cells must contain $j \neq k$ balls, each one.

My attempt was:

$$\frac
{ {n \choose m} {{r-mk+n-m-1} \choose {r-mk}} }
{ {{r+n-1} \choose {n-1}} } $$

Explain: we distribute $r$ indistinguishable balls into $n$ cells, so that's $|\Omega|={{r+n-1} \choose {n-1}}$ in the denominator.

In the numerator, I choose $m$ cells and puts inside each one of them $k$ balls (that make $mk$ balls in total. we have ${n \choose m}$ possibilities of doing that). Then, the rest of the $r-mk$ balls are distributed to the $n-m$ remaining cells (that's the ${{r-mk+n-m-1} \choose {r-mk}}$).

I believe my mistake was that i didn't made sure that the rest of the $n-m$ cells does not containing $k$ balls as well, so the numerator is "too big".
But i have no idea how to fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already mentioned in another answer, dealing with a probability problem one must treat all the balls as distinct (for example we can imagine the balls be numbered from $1$ to $r$) so that the number of all possible events is $n^r$.

Let
$$
N(r,n,k,m)
$$
be the number of the events with exactly $m$ cells containing exactly $k$ balls.

The solution for $m=0$ can be easily found with help of the [inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) and reads:
$$
N(r,n,k,0)=\sum_{j=0}^{\min(n,\frac rk)}(-1)^j\binom nj\frac{r!}{(k!)^j(r-kj)!}(n-j)^{r-kj},
$$
where the sum starts with the unrestricted number of possible events $n^r$. Generally the structure of the term is the following: the factor $\binom nj$ stays for the number of ways to choose $j$ cells filled with $k$ balls each, the multinomial coefficient $\frac{r!}{(k!)^j(r-kj)!}=\binom r{\underbrace{k,k,\dots,k}_j,r-kj}$ counts the number of ways to fill these $j$ cells with $k$ balls each, and finally $(n-j)^{r-kj}$ counts the number of ways to distribute the remaining $r-kj$ balls between the remaining $n-j$ cells.

Recognizing this the answer to the general case is simply:
$$
\begin{aligned}
N(r,n,k,m)&=\binom nm\frac{r!}{(k!)^m(r-km)!}N(r-km,n-m,k,0)\\
&=\binom nm\frac{r!}{(k!)^m(r-km)!}\sum_{j=m}^{\min(n,\frac rk)}(-1)^{j-m}\binom {n-m}{j-m}\frac{(r-km)!}{(k!)^{j-m}(r-kj)!}(n-j)^{r-kj}\\
&=\frac{n!r!}{m!}\sum_{j=m}^{\min(n,\frac rk)}\frac{(-1)^{j-m}(n-j)^{r-kj}}{(n-j)!(j-m)!(k!)^{j}(r-kj)!},\\
\end{aligned}
$$
and the probability in question reads:
$$
\frac{N(r,n,k,m)}{n^r}.
$$

Comment: Thank you! That's very helping!

Comment: @ryden You're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

$\color{black}{\text{BIG HINT:}}$ Your main mistake is to approach probability question like it is a combinatorics questions. Do not forget that if we work over probability , it does not matter whether balls or bins are distinguishable or not , you must see them as distinguishable. So , by using this information solve the question like distinguishable balls into distinguishable cells.If you cannot handle it , just ping me to expand my answer. By the way , exponential generating functions is a powerful tool to solve this question

Read  *[one of  my older answers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4326258/imagine-12-identical-balls-that-are-placed-in-3-different-boxes-what-is-the/4326273#4326273)* to understand the reason..

$\color{black}{\text{EXPANSION:}}$

I think that solving this question using "normal" way  is very cumbersome , you must use P.I.E etc. I am putting a *[link](https://www.math.brown.edu/mchan2/2019Spring_2520/StudentPresentations/George_Exponential_Generating_Functions.pdf)* here to learn E.G , and i will solve it using E.G.F.

First of all , for denominator , there are $n^r$ ways to disperse the balls into the cells.

Then , for numerator , select which cells will contain exactly $k$ elements by $C(n,m)$

After that , use E.G.F such that

- E.G.F for the cells which contain exactly $k$ elements is $\frac{x^k}{k!}$
- E.G.F for the cells which do not contain  $k$ elements is $\bigg(e^x -\frac{x^k}{k!} \bigg)$

Then , you must find the coefficient of $\frac{x^r}{r!}$ , in the expansion of $$\bigg(\frac{x^k}{k!} \bigg)^m \bigg(e^x -\frac{x^k}{k!} \bigg)^{n-m}$$

So , the answer is $$\frac{C(n,m) \times [x^r]\bigg[\bigg(\frac{x^k}{k!} \bigg)^m \bigg(e^x -\frac{x^k}{k!} \bigg)^{n-m}\bigg]}{n^r}$$

Comment: ok, i read your comment. That's an interesting thing there.. But still, i didn't quite get the idea of how to use it..
I haven't heard of exponential generating functions. Can you post your own answer in the "normal" way? maybe through that i'll understand your point.

Comment: Nice! Your solution looks good. 

Unfortunatly, we haven't learned exponential generating functions yet :\

But.. I just found this answer:
$$
\frac{m!r!}{m!n^r}\sum_j\frac{(n-j)^{r-jk}}{(j-m)!(n-j)!(r-jk)!(k!)^j}
$$
$$\text{when then sum is for $j \geq m$ s.t. $j \leq n,\; kj \leq r$}$$

The person who sent it to me claims this is the right answer too, but i don't understand it at all. Not that he knows how to explain it, he just heard it from one of the  lecturers. Do you see how is this working?